# iOS if conditional appears not to evaluate as expected. Dumb mistake or something funny?

Tags: ios, if-statement, magicalrecord

I've just added a conditional "if" statement to my code to set a label to "Undefined activity" if the user selects the same item consecutively from a list of possible activities, but I'm missing something because the if statement doesn't seem to catch the duplicate tap. Here's the code in question:

```
-(void) refreshData
{
    currentActivity = [TimedActivity MR_findFirstOrderedByAttribute:@"timedActivityTapped" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *timedActivityRecords = [TimedActivity MR_findAllSortedBy:@"timedActivityTapped" ascending:YES];
    previousActivity = [timedActivityRecords objectAtIndex:timedActivityRecords.count-2];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat: @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
    self.timeStampLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentActivity.timedActivityTapped];
    self.previousActivityLabel.text = previousActivity.timedActivityName;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    // This if statement should evaluate TRUE if the user taps the same activity consecutively
    // but control is skipping it as if it is FALSE
    if (currentActivity.timedActivityName == previousActivity.timedActivityName)
    {
        self.currentActivityLabel.text = @"Undefined activity";
    }
    else
    {
        self.currentActivityLabel.text = currentActivity.timedActivityName;
    }

    [self previousActivityDuration];
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the Activities list:

[image]

And here's a screenshot of the Report view, showing which activity is currently being timed, when it started, how long it's been running, the activity selected previously, and how long that activity ran:

[image]

As you can see, even though "Playing guitar" was selected twice, consecutively, the if statement fails to catch it and put the "Undefined activity" alternative text into the "In Progress" label.

I'm using Core Data and the MagicalRecord framework.

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong? I'm an admitted nooby, but so far so good until I ran into this.

Many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the if statement to

```
if ([currentActivity.timedActivityName isEqualToString:previousActivity.timedActivityName])
{
    self.currentActivityLabel.text = @"Undefined activity";
}
else
{
    self.currentActivityLabel.text = currentActivity.timedActivityName;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! I can see I have more work to do, because this just renames the time interval in the display. I also have to delete the underlying object and replace it with a new one with properly named attributes. Many thanks once again! I'd upvote you, but am still below the waterline.